# All permutations up until n = x

Tags: arrays, rust, permutation

Having a certain integer (for example n = 3) I want to have an array where each element is one of the possible permutations of the numbers up until n = 3. Example:

```
 n = 3, so numbers: [0,1,2]

 permutations: [(0),(1),(2), (0,1),(1,0),(0,2),...,(0,1,2),(0,2,1),(1,0,2),(1,2,0),...]
```

(This probably can be represented as an array of arrays in Rust)
How can this be achieved in Rust?

Comment: please provide at least some pseudo code of the algorithm you want.

Comment: One word of warning - stackoverflow isn't a coding service where one writes pseudocode and gets ready-made solutions. I'm letting this one slide, but the next time I see a similar quality question from you I'll flag it as "Low quality".

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, sure, I will try to bring up a partial solution if I can get to it.

Answer (score 2):

The short-and-sweet answer involves combining calls to [`IterTools::combinations`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations). There will be one caveat, though - we're going to need to return an owned struct, and this rules out slices in favor of vectors. The difference is almost negligible and you can always turn them back into slices:

```
user itertools::IterTools;
let items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let combinations = (1..=items.len()).fold(vec![], |mut state, to_take| {
  state.append(&mut items.iter().combinations(to_take).collect::<Vec<_>>());
  state
});
println!("{:?}", combinations)
```

The `combinations()` method itself is very straightforward to implement yourself in case you do not want to burden yourself with the (superior) implementation contained in `itertools`.

Comment: That includes all combinations but not all permutations, how can I add all permutations as well? For example for [1,2,4] also having [2,1,4],[1,4,2],[4,1,2],...

Comment: Implement `permutations()` yourself, either by wrapping `combinations()` or following [this algorithm primer](https://itnext.io/permutations-combinations-algorithms-cheat-sheet-68c14879aba5). The hard part of your question was how to combine heterogenous return sizes and working off dynamic factorials.